# Responsive design using inline-block

Tags: css

I simply design a HTML page using the inline-block to make it responsively. I set all block form image and text as inline-block, but the text block is moved under to the image block, how can I set the CSS and put the text block right beside the image block?

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/yckelvin/ar1f3uz5/

HTML code

```
<div class="item-row">
<div class="item-li"><img src="https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-t9e7S8huhaQ/VBMVN6CbNGI/AAAAAAAAA14/02am46_jiJM/s1600/Big_smile.png" width="150" height="150" /></div>
<div class="item-desc" ><h1>Item 1</h1>
Description Description Description Description Description Description Description Description Description Description </div>
</div>

<div class="item-row item-indent-row">
<div class="item-li"><img src="https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-t9e7S8huhaQ/VBMVN6CbNGI/AAAAAAAAA14/02am46_jiJM/s1600/Big_smile.png" width="150" height="150" /></div>
<div class="item-desc"><h1>Item 2</h1>
Description Description Description Description Description Description Description Description Description Description Description Description Description Description Description Description Description </div>
</div>
```

CSS code

```
.item-row { display: block; width: 100%; padding: 30px; background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1); }
.item-indent-row { padding-left: 150px; }
.item-li {display: inline-block; width:50px; background-color: rgba(255,255,0,0.1); }
.item-desc {display: inline-block; background-color: rgba(0,0,255,0.1); padding-left: 0px;}
```

Real sample

[image]

## Item 1

Description Description Description Description Description Description Description Description Description Description

[image]

## Item 2

Description Description Description Description Description Description Description Description Description Description Description Description Description Description Description Description Description

Comment: I tried the float but could not control the text block right beside the image block.

Answer (score 0):

```
.item-desc {
    display:block;
    width:200px; 
    /*Or whatever width you wanted the description 
      to be. Just make sure it's not too wide to fit on the same line
    */
    float:left; 
    background-color: rgba(0,0,255,0.1); 
    padding-left: 0px;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `white-space: nowrap;` for the `.item-row` and `white-space: normal;` for the `.item-desc`